# Showing $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$ given an integral condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_{n}: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a Borel measurable function such that $$\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)\log(2 + f_{n}(x))\, dx < \infty.$$ If $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ Lebesgue almost everywhere. Then the problem is to show that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}$.

The hint says to consider $g_{n}(x) = \max(f_{n}(x), \lambda)$ for certain $\lambda$. Can anyone give another hint to this problem? I'm not sure what I'd use the $g_{n}$ for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample

Let $f_n(x) = n^2$ when $x \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Then $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\log(f_n(x) +2)dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} n^2 \log(n^2 + 2)dx = n\log(n^2) + 2 < \infty$

We know that almost sure $f_n$ converges to the null function. But the convergence does not happen in $L^1$ since $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = n$